# Создание обьектов Типа согласно ячейкам Шахматной доски

Tags: c#, любой-язык

Подскажите как реализовать вот такую идею List'ом (наверное, только не List в List'е), ибо двумерные, рваные массивы не подходят по условиям задачи, Dictionary тоже.

Идея такова:

- Есть тип Board и ссылка на тип Field(Поле игровой доски)
- У каждого обьекта типа Field разные поля. Например:
- (PositionField =    a1, color = white)
- (PositionField = a2, color = black)
- ...
- (PositionField = b8, color = black)
- Как сделать лист из 64 обьектов(типа Field), но что бы это был
  максимально сжатый и красивый код, а то у меня в голове, только 64
  обьекта инициализировать вручную

Comment: @Igor, пожалуйста) Да, похоже, что дело именно в этом. В экране правок кнопки на месте и выполняют код)

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что пришло в голову. Если у вашего Field другие поля, то поправьте (например, Color на string). Инициализирует список длиной 64 значениями Field с чередующимся цветом клетки.

```
struct MapFiled
{
    public readonly char Row;
    public readonly int Line;
    public readonly Color Color;

    public MapFiled(char row, int line, Color color)
    {
        Row = row;
        Line = line;
        Color = color;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<MapFiled> map = new List<MapFiled>(64);

    bool isFieldBlack = true;
    for (char row = 'A'; row <= 'H'; row++, isFieldBlack = !isFieldBlack)
        for (int line = 1; line <= 8; line++, isFieldBlack = !isFieldBlack)
            map.Add(new MapFiled(row, line, isFieldBlack ? Color.Black : Color.White));
}
```